# Accessing different computers files under OSX with Ruby

Tags: ruby, networking, file-io

I would like to write a ruby app that is hosted on a local server that can copy files to other computers located in the same building but am having trouble finding exactly where to start when it comes to accessing the different directories. The part I need a push in the right direction, is authenticating with the computer to access the file system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Net::SFTP](https://github.com/net-ssh/net-sftp) as a starting point. It has the capabilities to allow you to securely authenticate, list directories, create/delete directories and files.

See the examples in the documentation for more information.

"[Net::SFTP FAQ](http://net-ssh.github.io/sftp/v1/faq.html)" will help also.

Comment: do all OSX computers run SFTP?

Comment: I don't know about all of them. I know *mine* do.